# Kotlin - associateBy multiple keys

Tags: kotlin

I have the following list:

```kotlin
val d1 = Data(keys = listOf("a", "b"), ...)
val d2 = Data(keys = listOf("c"), ...)

val list = listOf(d1, d2)
```

Now I want to transform that list to the following map:

```kotlin
val map = mapOf(
    "a" to d1,
    "b" to d1,
    "c" to d2
)
```

Keys are unique per Data object.

I want something like `associateByAll` that maps multiple keys to the same object:

```kotlin
val map = list.associateByAll { it.keys }
```

What is best way to do this in Kotlin?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how flatten would do anything here since there is no list of lists. Also the question would be same even if the Data object would only consist of the keys paramter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val result = list
    .flatMap { data -> data.keys.map { it to data } }
    .toMap()
```

Inside `flatMap`, we associate each of an item's keys to the item. Flattening it creates a List of pairs of key to its Data instance. Then `toMap` turns that into a Map. If a key appears in more than one Data instance, the last one will "win".

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it does exactly what I want!